# Ubuntu 20.04 vpnc: unknown host

Tags: networking, vpn, vpnc

I would like to connect to my FritzBox via VPN. I used their manual to do so, but the VPN Connection failed. I have checked the syslogs:

```
Feb  6 09:04:43 pc NetworkManager[54617]: /usr/sbin/vpnc: unknown host `xxx.myfritz.net'
```

I have tried to use `/usr/sbin/vpnc` directly witht the same result.
I also tried using the IP adress directly instead of the hostname, same result.
`nslookup` can resolve the host. But it is IPV6 only, could this be the problem?

```
Ubuntu 20.04
vpnc version 0.5.3r550-3.1
```

Comment: You're trying to connect to a `xxx.myfritz.net` host presumably on public Internet - can you confirm that there are DNS entries for it? Also, is the actual VPN server behind a NAT, in which case is the traffic/port forwarding active? A little more about your topology and redacted copy of the config might help...

Comment: The VPN "server" is a Fritzbox Cable 6591. The address behind xxx.myfritz.net can be resolved on public dns servers. Also can do my local dns server. But vpnc seems have a problem with the ipv6 only address. I tried to use the ip directly, or other ipv6 only hostnames, all resulting in `unknown host`. Using IPV4 adresses/hosts has no problems.